# Create tags for files using ctags

Tags: vim, tag

I'm using ctags to create a tags file for use in Vim in a latex project. I have a main.tex file and several files in the chapters directory such as chapters/chapter1.tex. I have the following code in the main.tex file:

```
\include{chapters/chapter1}
```

I want to be able to jump to chapter1.tex by pressing ^] on the chapter1 above. Currently by running the command

```
ctags -R extras=+f
```

It only creates a tag for 'chapter1.tex' and I can only jump if the text is exactly 'chapter1.tex'. How can change ctags configuration to create a tag for 'chapter1' instead of 'chapter1.tex'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `gf` mapping of vim which opens the file under the cursor. Bonus point, you directly jump to the last known position. Moreover, there is the vim option [`suffixesadd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27suffixesadd%27) to automatically add extensions such as `.tex` when looking for files. I personnaly added `.cls` to directly open package files.

That is, you don't need the `extras=+f` of ctags.